# making a python program executable

Tags: py2exe

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    windows = [{'script': "single.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

in this setup file for py2exe where it says single.py is that where I place the name of my program?

Comment: See also:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file

Answer (score 5):

I don't know your py2exe tool, but we usually use this way to convert py to exe:

1. Download and install Standard Python Software:
   http://www.python.org/download/
2. Download PyInstaller via link below:
   http://pyinstaller.python-hosting.com/
3. Unpack the archive, that you have downloaded! 
   In this examople, the directory of the unpacked files:
4. In the `<UNPACKED_FILES_DIR>` directory, run Configure.py. 
   It must be run before trying to build anything.
5. Create a spec file for your project:

   ```
   python Makespec.py -F -p <PYTHON_LIB_PATH> <PYTHON_SCRIPT>
     -F: Produce a single file deployment.
     -p <PYTHON_LIB_PATH>: Set base path for import (like using PYTHONPATH).
        ( e.g.: C:\Program Files\Python24\Lib\ )
     <PYTHON_SCRIPT>: Path to python script.
   ```

6 Build your project!

```
    python Build.py <SPECFILE>
      <SPECFILE>: Path to the specfile, that have been created in step 4! 

    The full path to <SPECFILE>:
      <UNPACKED_FILES_DIR>/<PYTHON_SCRIPT>/<PYTHON_SCRIPT>.spec
```

7. The binary file will be placed in the directory of `<SPECFILE>`.

Answer (score 3):

If you can restrict your code, then [Shed Skin](http://shed-skin.blogspot.com/), [PyPy](http://www.rfk.id.au/blog/entry/compiling-rpython-programs/), or [Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581784/can-cython-compile-to-an-exe) make true, fast executables.

[Py2exe, PyInstaller, or bbfreeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file) can package Python up to 2.7 into single executables.

[Cx_Freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2553886/819417) packages Python up to 3.x into an executable plus many other files.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Are you making a windowing application or a console application? See the example setup.py files that came with py2exe.