# How do I include files within multiple folders in cx_Freeze

Tags: python, pygame, cx-freeze

I am trying to make my pygame into an exe file, but I don't know how to include files that are in multiple folders? Thanks

Comment: Could you extend the solution to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079268/how-can-i-include-a-folder-with-cx-freeze eventually following the link in there to still another question (one folder and other files respectively)? What are your current build options?

Comment: I tried it but it still won't work. Could you help me to export it to exe file if that's possible? The github link is [link](https://github.com/SuperMage03/OverPaint.git)