# Include entire folders in cx_Freeze with pygame

Tags: python, file, directory, pygame, cx-freeze

I have been following a tutorial on how to make a cx_freeze setup for pygame folders. Here is what I have come up with...

```
import cx_Freeze
executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("mainGame - Copy.py")]
cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "Cave",
    version = "1.0",
    author = "Owen Pennington",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame"], "include_files":["floor_heart.wav"]}},
    executables = executables
    )
```

However the rest of my files are in folders. Then there are folders inside these folders. For example I have a folder (path directory) `C:CaveGame\Sprites` and this folder holds many other folders, `C:CaveGame\Sprites\Floors`, `C:CaveGame\Sprites\Lava` ect... Then I also have a folder `C:CaveGame\Music` which holds all my music files and sound effects. How can I get these all to work inside the setup???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I include a folder with cx\_freeze?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079268/how-can-i-include-a-folder-with-cx-freeze)

Comment: I don't know the exact code to include the files whilst including the pygame package :/ But it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to include the upper-level directory item in your `options` dictionary:

```
setup(name='Widgets Test',
      version = '1.0',
      description = 'Test of Text-input Widgets',
      author = "Fred Nurks",
      options = { "build_exe": {"packages":["pygame"], "include_files":["assets/", "music/"] } },
      executables = executables
      )
```

The above example will include the files `assets/images/blah.png` and `music/sounds/sproiiiing.ogg` along with their correct directories.  *Everything* under that top-level folder is pulled into the `lib/`.

When you go to load these files, it's necessary to work out the exact path to the files.  But the normal method to do this does not work with cxFreeze.  Referencing the FAQ at https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html ~

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    EXE_LOCATION = os.path.dirname( sys.executable ) # frozen
else:
    EXE_LOCATION = os.path.dirname( os.path.realpath( __file__ ) ) # unfrozen
```

Obviously you need the modules `sys` and `os.path` for this.

Then when loading a file, determine the full path with `os.path.join`:

```
my_image_filename = os.path.join( EXE_LOCATION, "assets", "images", "image.png" )
image = pygame.image.load( my_image_filename ).convert_alpha()
```

EDIT: If you're building under Windows, you will need to also include the Visual C runtime: https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-package . Add `include_msvcr` to `options`.

```
options = { "build_exe": { "include_msvcr", "packages":["pygame"] #...
```