# How to package a python program with pyqt4 module by cxfreeze

Tags: python, pyqt4

I wrote a program using PyQt4.QtGui and QtCore,I packaged it into exe,and it works good on my computer,but it can't run on others' computer

**The error is this:**

```
cx_Freeze: Python error in main script
---------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console3.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "baidu.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\32-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1607, in _handle_fromlist
  File "C:\Python\32-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python\32-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1558, in _find_and_load
  File "C:\Python\32-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1525, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "ExtensionLoader_PyQt4_QtGui.py", line 11, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。
```

**The packaged files are:**

```
├─_bz2.pyd
├─_hashlib.pyd
├─_socket.pyd
├─_ssl.pyd
├─baidu.exe
├─icudt49.dll
├─icuin49.dll
├─icuuc49.dll
├─LIBEAY32.dll
├─libGLESv2.dll
├─lxml.etree.pyd
├─PyQt4.QtCore.pyd
├─PyQt4.QtGui.pyd
├─PyQt4.QtNetwork.pyd
├─python33.dll
├─Qt5Core.dll
├─Qt5Gui.dll
├─Qt5Network.dll
├─Qt5PrintSupport.dll
├─Qt5Widgets.dll
├─sip.pyd
├─SSLEAY32.dll
└─unicodedata.pyd
```

I just used "cxfreeze baidu.py --base-name=Win32GUI --target-dir d:\123" to package it.
I wonder if I missed some arguments when using cxfreeze result in this problem,and how to package it to exe.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d3dcompiler_43.dll` is needed to run pyqt

Comment: I was about to say that a DLL seems to be missing, since the error translated is `Can not find the specified module`.  Next time this happens, check the specified line number and verify the DLL it is trying to load. Have you been able to package the DLL using cx_freeze? If not, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553886/how-can-i-bundle-other-files-when-using-cx-freeze.