# python 3.2 tkinter icon with cx_freeze

Tags: python, tkinter, icons, cx-freeze

i am using this, which works fine when i start the python script

```
root.wm_iconbitmap('icon.ico')
```

but after compiling the script with cx_freeze and trying to execute the compiled file i get the following error message

```
File "D:\Programme\Python\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1553, in wm_iconbitmap
return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "icon.ico" not defined
```

so the icon file can not be found.
how to configure my setup.py to include the icon file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i bundle other files when using cx\_freeze?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553886/how-can-i-bundle-other-files-when-using-cx-freeze)

Comment: See also [using data files](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files) in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you have fixed this issue or not (given how old this question is) but I had the exact same issue as you and thanks to your question it actually solved my problem.

In order to include your icon file (or any other file that your Python program calls upon) you create a variable in your `setup.py` script called `includefiles` and then in the `setup(` code include `options`.

Below is the the `setup.py` script I used to do this.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if (sys.platform == "win32"):
    base = "Win32GUI"

exe = Executable(
        script = "Binary to Decimal Converter.py",
        icon = "python-xxl.ico",
        targetName = "Binary to Decimal Converter.exe",
        base = base
        )
includefiles = ["python-xxl.ico"]

setup(
    name = "Binary to Decimal Converter",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Converts Binary values to Decimal values",
    author = "Neeraj Morar",
    options = {'build_exe': {'include_files':includefiles}},
    executables = [exe]
)
```

As you can see, `includefiles` consists of my icon file name (which I should remind you to have the file in the same directory as your Python script). Then, in the `setup(` code I have `options = {'build_exe': {'include_files':includefiles}}`

The `'include_files'` calls upon the `includefiles` variable I have created.

Essentially, all you need to do is do the same thing as me, but instead of my icon file name put in your icon file name; i.e. `includefiles = ["icon.ico"]`.

Comment: Now working anymore. `_tkinter.TclError Could not open \C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\AppName\library.zip\icon.png. No such file or directory`

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: @ajinzrathod it seems your filepath doesn't look right, it seems to be treating your C: drive as a subfolder, due the to `\\` at the beginning of the path. Without seeing your code, If you put your icon in the same directory as your Python script, and simply refer to the name "icon.png" it should work.

Comment: Oh I am sorry. I forgot to mentioned. I used `python setup.py bdist_msi` and created MSI installer. Also I created a desktop shortcut. So when I open from desktop, it does not work. But it does work from root directory where the application is