# cx_freeze not importing external modules

Tags: python, pywin32, cx-freeze, pyhook

I choose to try using cx_freeze which converts my simple python 3.x keylogger to an exe. I choose cx_freeze because py2exe is only python 2.x I am compiling my code using this setup.py script.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
buildOptions = dict(packages = [], excludes = [])

base = 'Console'

executables = [
    Executable('logger.py', base=base, targetName = 'logger.exe')
]

setup(name='PyLogger',
      version = '0.1',
      description = 'A Simple Keylogger',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

and I when I compile my code which is

```
try:
    import pythoncom
except ImportError:
    input("Import Error, pywin32 is not installed")

try:
    import pyHook
except ImportError:
    input("Import Error, pyHook is not installed")
```

I get the import error saying both pywin32 and pyHook is not installed. How do you import external modules into cx_freeze.

EDIT - I have tried changing the setup.py to add the includes option but it made no difference.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
buildOptions = dict(packages = ['pyHook','pythoncom'],includes = ['pyHook','pythoncom'], excludes = [])

base = 'Console'

executables = [
    Executable('logger.py', base=base, targetName = 'logger.exe')
]

setup(name='PyLogger',
      version = '0.1',
      description = 'A Simple Keylogger',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

Comment: Can you show the output from freezing your application? Also, are those packages in zipped eggs? cx_Freeze currently has trouble finding modules in zipped eggs, but I've got [a pull request](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/pull-request/38/finding-packages-inside-zip-files) to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Find the .pyd file of the external module.  Copy and paste that into the build file.  So, for example, if it was looking for _cpyHook (I had the same problem as you and it said that module was missing), go to  C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\pyHook and copy and paste the file into C:\Python33\build\exe.win-amd64-3.3.

Answer (score 0):

Try listing the missing packages explicitly in the build options like so:

```
buildOptions = dict(packages = ['pyHook', 'pywin32'], excludes = [])
```

And see the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553886/) if you need to include other (non-Python) files in your build.

*EDIT*: I finally had time to look at this a little more, and it seems to be a tricky problem.  I'll keeping poking at it as time permits, but I thought I'd post my findings in case they're useful to the OP.  I suspect that the `pyHook` module doesn't play nice when 'frozen', i.e., when it's included in a zip file.  If I use this `setup.py`:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

buildOptions = dict(
    includes=['pythoncom'],
    packages=['pyHook']
)

executables = [
    Executable('logger.py', base='Console', targetName = 'logger.exe')
]

setup(
    name='PyLogger',
    version = '0.1',
    description = 'A Simple Keylogger',
    options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
    executables = executables
)
```

the generated `logger.exe` does not—initially, at least—run correctly, and generates the error:

```
Import Error, pyHook is not installed
```

However, if I run the following command from the directory containing the EXE:

```
unzip library.zip
```

and re-run `logger.exe`, then everything seems to work fine. It's just not able to load `pyHook` from the `library.zip` file that `cx_Freeze` generates.  I've seen this kind of problem before in the past, and worked around it by munging `sys.path` in my top-level script prior to loading any modules.  I'll see if I can dig up one of those examples.  In the meantime, perhaps this advice will help the OP: try unzipping the zip file and see if it makes a difference.  A couple things to note:

- I'm not having any problems importing `pywin32`, only `pyHook`
- I *did* try setting `create_shared_zip=False` and `include_in_shared_zip=False` in the build options, but this just resulted in a file named `logger.zip` instead of `library.zip`. (Weird. I can't believe that's not a bug.)

Comment: Sorry, I think you need to set ``includes`` rather than ``packages`` in your ``buildOptions`` dict. I'm not in a place where I can verify this at the moment, but I'll check and update my answer accordingly as soon as I am.

Comment: Just updated my main post adding the includes, however pyHook and pywin32 are still not being imported correctly.