# Compiling a python script to .exe that imports from another .py file and .csv

Tags: python, exe

So... simple question: I'm trying to use cx_Freeze to build an .exe file.

In my script I import some packages, functions from another .py file and also an array from a .csv file.

How do I compile this into one .exe file / a directory containing an .exe file?

I've noticed that there is a "options" parameter, which I tried filling with

```
"packages": ["numpy","pandas","userinput","Atoms.csv"]
```

But no luck. The .exe file just opens and closes again

EDIT
So I've changed the setup.py to

```
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable

includefiles = ['Atoms.csv','userinput.py']
includes = []
excludes = []
packages = ['numpy','pandas']

setup(
    name = 'Molar mass',
    version = '1.0',
    description = 'A calculator for the molar mass',
    author = '',
    options = {'build_exe': {'includes':includes,'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includefiles}}, 
    executables = [Executable('Molarmass.py')]
)
```

Which gives me the error "ImportError: No module named 'numpy'"
And if I try to run it without the packages, I can't open the .exe file.

Comment: Could you give your Python project tree structure? Do you use Python packaging? See: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553886/how-can-i-bundle-other-files-when-using-cx-freeze

Comment: I think you should not include Atoms.csv in packages