# Can Cython compile to an EXE?

Tags: python, compilation, cython

I know what Cythons purpose is.  It's to write compilable C extensions in a Python-like language in order to produce speedups in your code.  What I would like to know (and can't seem to find using my google-fu) is if Cython can somehow compile into an executable format since it already seems to break python code down into C.

I already use Py2Exe, which is just a packager, but am interested in using this to compile down to something that is a little harder to unpack (Anything packed using Py2EXE can basically just be extracted using 7zip which I do not want)

It seems if this is *not* possible my next alternative would just be to compile all my code and load it as a module and then package that using py2exe at least getting *most* of my code into compiled form, right?

Comment: Linked to [Making an executable in Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507592/making-an-executable-in-cython)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In principal it appears to be possible to do something like what you want, according to the [Embedding Pyrex HOWTO](http://www.freenet.org.nz/python/embeddingpyrex/).  (Pyrex is effectively a previous generation of Cython.)

Hmm... that name suggests a better search than I first tried: "embedding cython" leads to [this page](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/EmbeddingCython) which sounds like what you want.

Comment: Please see my example of how to do exactly that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22040484/2198548) for a Linux system.

Answer (score 48):

[Here's the wiki page on embedding cython](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/EmbeddingCython)

Assuming you installed python to `C:\Python31` and you want to use Microsoft Compiler.

`smalltest1.py` - is the file you want to compile.

`test.exe` - name of the executable.

You need to set the environmental variables for `cl`.

```
C:\Python31\python.exe C:\Python31\Scripts\cython.py smalltest1.py --embed

cl.exe  /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic:\Python31\include -Ic:\Python31\PC /Tcsmalltest1.c /link /OUT:"test.exe" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MACHINE:X86 /LIBPATH:c:\Python31\libs /LIBPATH:c:\Python31\PCbuild
```

Comment: Waw, it works very well. At the end the .exe file is really tiny. This is really a `cython2exe` similar to `py2exe` !
Could we do a script that does this automatically (adapt to the current Python version installed, etc.) ?

What files do we need to ship with this .exe ?

Comment: I am getting the errors `ignoring unknown option /main.c`, `
missing source filename`

Comment: From where to get `cython.py` file?

Comment: what is cl.exe ??

Comment: Microsoft c++ compiler

Answer (score 6):

I have successfully used the Cython & gcc to convert the *.py file to *.exe, with below batch file:

```
# build.bat
set PROJECT_NAME=test
set PYTHON_DIR=C:\python27
%PYTHON_DIR%\python -m cython --embed -o %PROJECT_NAME%.c %PROJECT_NAME%.py
gcc -Os -I %PYTHON_DIR%\include -o %PROJECT_NAME%.exe %PROJECT_NAME%.c -lpython27 -lm -L %PYTHON_DIR%\libs
```

Answer (score 2):

Aftershock's answer is good, what I want to say is about run app without console. Most like Aftershock's answer, if you want your application run without console, two points are important:

1. Replace all the `main()` function in the ".c" file made by `cython --embed` with `wmain()`
2. Add `/subsystem:windows /entry:wmainCRTStartup` to the end of `cl.exe ...`  command

Comment: Very useful indeed! `/subsystem:windows /entry:wmainCRTStartup` was required indeed (1. was not necessary for me).

Comment: How to do the same with gcc ? (mingw64)