# How to convert python scripts executable in python?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, executable

I am trying to convert a python scripts as an executable file for Linux.

I use freeze.py script to convert a python script into an executable file.

I get this output:

```
~$ python freeze.py carbuddy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "freeze.py", line 100, in <module>
import checkextensions
File "/home/darknight/checkextensions.py", line 6, in <module>
import parsesetup
ImportError: No module named parsesetup
```

(Where `carbuddy.py` is the scripts which I would like to convert into an executable)

Comment: dont you need only $ chmod +x carbuddy.py ?!?

Comment: but nothing will happen when i type chmod +x carbuddy.py

Comment: how come?? x make your file executable

Comment: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-make-a-python-script-executable-on-unix.htm

Comment: thanks  but when i try to open that executable file this msg   Invalid url: '/home/darknight/build/carbuddy/carbuddy' given, exiting

No ':' in the uri     shows

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware of freeze.py but I haven't worked with it that much. I've been trying to use it in my system (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) but I'm getting the same error as you. So, unfortunately, I can't help that much if you really want to use freeze.py.

But if you are trying to make executables, why don't you look at Cython? It is not exactly meant for making binary executables out of Python but it is possible. You'd have to invoke GCC (which is longer to type than good ol' freeze) but that's the only downside as far as I can tell. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22040484/777225) SO answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using other tools, like http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/ ?