# Is there a way to compile a python application into static binary?

Tags: python, build

What I'm trying to do is ship my code to a remote server, that may have different python version installed and/or may not have packages my app requires.

Right now to achieve such portability I have to build relocatable virtualenv with interpreter and code. That approach has some issues (for example, you have to manually copy a bunch of libraries into your virtualenv, since `--always-copy` doesn't work as expected) and generally slow.

There's (in theory) [a way](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BuildStatically) to build python itself statically.

I wonder if I could pack interpreter with my code into one binary and run my application as module. Something like that: `./mypython -m myapp run` or `./mypython -m gunicorn -c ./gunicorn.conf myapp.wsgi:application`.

Comment: Do you mean something like cx_freeze?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, I've never heard of cx_freeze until today. Looked through docs, seems like it's what I want, but it fails to build on Ubuntu 12.04.5 with python3.5.1. I'm looking for alternatives, thanks for kick in the right direction.

Comment: Sadly, pyinstaller doesn't work with Django 1.9 and py2app/py2exe don't support linux :(

Comment: if cx_Freeze and pyinstaller don't work, there is still hope. You can create package(s) for your target distribution(s) which will resolve all dependencies on installation.

Or, maybe use something like docker to run your app.

Comment: pyinstaller works perfect on Windows!

Comment: other options are nuitka and cython

Comment: If you have a spare hour, this is very good talk about shipping python - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BqAeN-F9Qs

Comment: I think cx_freeze is really what you want, so we might be able to help you more if you shared the error...  Is it [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/32/cant-compile-cx_freeze-in-ubuntu-1304) by any chance?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

There are two ways you could go about to solve your problem

1. Use a static builder, like freeze, or `pyinstaller`, or `py2exe`
2. Compile using `cython`

This answer explains how you can go about doing it using the second approach, since the first method is not cross platform and version, and has been explained in other answers. Also, using programs like pyinstaller typically results in huge file sizes, while using cython will result in a file that's much smaller

1. First, install `cython`.

   ```sh
   sudo -H pip3 install cython
   ```
2. Then, you can use `cython` to generate a C file out of the Python `.py` file
   (in reference to https://stackoverflow.com/a/22040484/5714445)

   ```sh
   cython example_file.py --embed
   ```
3. Use GCC to compile it after getting your current python version (Note: The below assumes you are trying to compile it to Python3)

   ```sh
   PYTHONLIBVER=python$(python3 -c 'import sys; print(".".join(map(str, sys.version_info[:2])))')$(python3-config --abiflags)
   gcc -Os $(python3-config --includes) example_file.c -o output_bin_file $(python3-config --ldflags) -l$PYTHONLIBVER
   ```

You will now have a binary file `output_bin_file`, which is what you are looking for

**Other things to note**:

1. Change `example_file.py` to whatever file you are actually trying to compile.
2. Cython is used to use C-Type Variable definitions for static memory allocation to speed up Python programs. In your case however, you will still be using traditional Python definitions.
3. If you are using additional libraries (like `opencv`, for example), you might have to provide the directory to them using `-L` and then specify the name of the library using `-l` in the GCC Flags. For more information on this, please refer to GCC flags
4. The above method might not work for anaconda python, as you will likely have to install a version of gcc that is compatible with your conda-python.

Comment: Hi, what if my application spans across multiple files. This approach seems to only compile the current script and not all the Python dependencies.

Comment: no need to rename your python file (say test.py) into a pyx right now

Comment: This was of great help to me. To answer the question about multiple files, you could use cythonize: `cythonize -i file_0.py [...] file_n.py` for all your python modules, then `cython main_file.py --embed` for your main script. You'll end up with an executable and .so files (.dll, .dylib depending on your OS) that you can use together as a standalone solution.

Comment: I am getting "No modules named encodings". I got to know I require certain files from python installation. However, my target system doesn't have python. Please help.

Comment: Warning: Cython requires dynamically loading stuff, and it DOES NOT produce self-contained binaries. Don't waste your time!

Comment: Also note that you'll need to specify the Python directory during build or you will get fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found for the include line #include "Python.h" (which is what the posted command produces).

Answer (score 18):

You might wish to investigate [Nuitka](http://nuitka.net/pages/download.html). It takes python source code and converts it in to C++ API calls. Then it compiles into an executable binary (ELF on Linux). It has been around for a few years now and supports a wide range of Python versions.

You will probably also get a performance improvement if you use it. Recommended.

Comment: I couldn't find any information about using Nuitka with Django. Do you, by any chance, have such experience?

Comment: @roboslone, Prakhar Agarwal Cython supports external libraries really well, when compared to Nuitka PyPy's static builder. For instance, from the link at the end of this comment, "people use Cython because it helps them solve a problem. Which is either that they want to connect to external non-Python libraries from Python code or that they want to be able to manually optimise their code, or both.", the link being http://blog.behnel.de/posts/indexp241.html

Comment: R. S. Nikhil Krishna, I'm not trying to make my code faster, I'm trying to ship it in one binary with python interpreter inside.

Comment: Aah okay. I thought you wanted to bind it with some external library. My bad.

Answer (score 5):

You're probably looking for something like Freeze, which is able to compile your Python application with all its libraries into a static binary:

[PyPi page of Freeze](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze)

[Python Wiki page of Freeze](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze)

[Sourceforge page of Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Actually, all current python packaging tool is doing fake package. They strongly rely on libc. Once you put those fake binary file into ubuntu7 and run them, you'll see many errors.

Comment: I simply wish someone could do a full static compilling for python. So that the final binary excutable will get running even without glibc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a Mac you can use py2app to create a .app bundle, which starts your Django app when you double-click on it.

I described how to bundle Django and CherryPy into such a bundle at https://moosystems.com/articles/14-distribute-django-app-as-native-desktop-app-01.html

In the article I use pywebview to display your Django site in a local application window.

Comment: My application runs on Linux mostly, so py2app doesn't apply

Comment: Though the article uses py2app, it can be done using pyinstaller, too.

Answer (score 1):

Freeze options:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbfreeze/1.1.3
- http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/

However, your target server should have the environment you want -> you should be able to 'create' it. If it doesn't, you should build your software to match the environment.

I found this handy guide on how to install custom version of python to a virtualenv, assuming you have ssh access: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5507373/5616110

In virtualenv, you should be able to pip install anything and you shouldn't need to worry about sudo privileges. Of course, having those and access to package manager like apt makes everything a lot easier.

Comment: I'm already using virtualenv, this is not the case. My question is about statically compiled python witn required modules and applications.

Comment: Then you have to freeze it, no other way around that.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a docker image that relies on Nuitka and a custom statically linked python3.10 to create a static binary.

Did not test it extensively, if you have the chance please let me know if it works for your use case.

You can check it at:
https://github.com/joaompinto/docker-build-python-static-bin

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it is working in ubuntu7.

Comment: And based on your docker file, I even compiled all python module, so that the whole python3.10.4 is full statically usable in any amd64 machine: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nR1owjXuzoxOw9lie5Js5JyCOI1xscBQ/view?usp=sharing