# Is there a way to hide a line of code in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a way that I can hide a line of code in Python that is unreadable to everyone except the program?.

Comment: I think you need to provide more details about the situation.

Comment: hi, the other answer has solved the problem. I was searching using the wrong terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share your code and keep stuff secret as well you are better off compiling your code, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913847/is-there-a-way-to-compile-python-application-into-static-binary)

Comment: thanks, I will look at compiling.