# How to convert Python code to executable?

Tags: python, executable-format

So I have a python code now that I want other folks to use. They don't have Python installed on their computers.
I have seen people convert their code to .exe so others can use it even if they don't have Python on their machines.

How can I do this? Is there a special software needed for this?

Thank you

Comment: Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913847/is-there-a-way-to-compile-python-application-into-static-binary

Comment: Your friends are more comfortable with running some random .exe than with installing Python? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pyinstaller` library. Then you can create the file with

```
pyinstaller --onefile yourFileName.py
```

Comment: I installed pyinstaller and used the above line of code. I think it went through (I did not get any errors). But I am unable to locate the .exe file now. There is an 'Application' file by the same name of my project in the 'dist' folder. When I double click on it it opens as myProjectName.exe but eventually it says - failed to run script myProjectName.exe and the window closes

Comment: Could you send any print screen from your error? Eventually, you have to navigate to the script´s folder in order to execute the command line correctly and generate the .exe file.

Comment: Have you put the right extension .py in your command? This error may mean that the file is trying to execute myProjectName.exe instead of myProjectName.py. Could you also check it?

Comment: I saved my project as a .py in the Python38\Scripts folder. In cmd prompt I then navigated to this folder. Then I used the - pyinstaller --onefile -w projectname.py command.  ' 59157 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.' this is what I then got.      There also is a 'dist' and a 'build' folder now. I went into the dist folder where there is the myProject application file. When I double click on it now it just straightaway gives a fatal error: Failed to execute script myProject

Comment: I need more information about your error. Just try to record your screen while you execute the .exe file. Recording because the execution it´s too fast and maybe you cannot read clearly the error.