# Encrypting the source code of a python project

Tags: python, security, encryption, privacy, source-code-protection

I am working on an application where clients can build the application to their locale system but they should **not** be able to access the source code of the project, what is the best approach to do that?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40057634/1393899