# Why can't I run my python executables in busybox?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable, glibc, busybox

The setup is as follows:

I have a device with very limited ressources and busybox is running on it.
With PyInstaller I have built an executable out of my python script on a linux system with the same architecture. I know that the executables are compatible, there is no doubt.
There is only one problem: The executable still does not run:

```
[37832] Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEIEmDggN/libpython3.11.so.1.0': dlopen: /usr/lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.35' not found (required by /tmp/_MEIEmDggN/libpython3.11.so.1.0)
```

I understand the error and wanted to find out which glibc version is installed, but I cant find out by any means.

`ldd --version` for example does not yield any results (ldd not found)

I know for sure that there is a c library installed, because there are other python executables running on there. How do I find out which one and what version? I want to built the executable with that specific version then.Building the executable on the device itself is not an option, it has very little storage and performance to always pull all the dependencies and bundle them.

Comment: You won't find it because busybox does not have glibc.  It also does not have much else for other libraries depending on what you want to do.

Comment: @possum As I said, I know that there is a c library on there and other python executables can run. I am no expert for busybox, but surely there can be custom builds that include specific librarys or they are just installed later (?)

Comment: I think to move forward you should include the details of whatever target device you have and what capabilities it supports.  It does not necessarily have a C library (or any library) at all if everything happened to be compiled and running statically.  You could try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913847/is-there-a-way-to-compile-a-python-application-into-static-binary

Comment: Thank you, I`ll look into that. What confuses me, is that one of the suggestions is to use a static builder (PyInstaller among the examples) but the executables built by PyInstaller are apparently still in need of a C library.

The device is a custom board with a custom version of busybox. But there are python executables on there that run without problems. Also, there are other services running on it that rely on C.

Comment: The thread you provided was promising but every mentioned option is accused of not being self contained. glibc is also mentioned as a common dependeny that is not included in regular build processes of pyinstaller, pyoxidize or even the accepted answers suggestion of using cython ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is only one problem: The executable still does not run

The executable doesn't run because it requires (was linked against) GLIBC-2.35 (or newer) but is running on a machine with older version of GLIBC.

This also has *nothing* to do with busybox.

You must either:

- update GLIBC on the target to 2.35 (or newer), or
- compile and link `libpython3.11.so.1.0` against whatever version you have on the target (or older).

The second fix could be done by building `Python` in a `chroot` or a docker with appropriate (old) GLIBC.

---

> `ldd --version` for example does not yield any results (ldd not found)

You can find which version you have without `ldd` -- just run `/usr/lib64/libc.so.6` by itself and it will print its version.

Comment: Thank you! I knew what I needed to find out but I didn't knew how.