# Compling Python3 to a binary excutable on mac

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, gcc, cython

I'm tying to compile a python 3 command line program to a binary executable on Mac OS X.  I'm following these directions

[Compile main Python program using Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105482/compile-main-python-program-using-cython)

My install of python3 was done with homebrew but when I try to run

`gcc -Os -I /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Headers -o at_analyzer at_analyzer.c -lpython3.5m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl -v`

I get the following error :

```
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.12.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name at_analyzer.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu penryn -target-linker-version 274.1 -v -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -I /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Headers -Os -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/alex/Source/AT_analyzer -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 150 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.12.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -o /var/folders/8l/3c5cnrvj1hg_qbr73dz1pnq40000gn/T/at_analyzer-e9d098.o -x c at_analyzer.c
clang -cc1 version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1) default target x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Headers
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.12.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -o at_analyzer /var/folders/8l/3c5cnrvj1hg_qbr73dz1pnq40000gn/T/at_analyzer-e9d098.o -lpython3.5m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
ld: library not found for -lpython3.5m
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I needed to specify the -L flag with the path that points to the library.

`gcc -Os -I /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Headers -L /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib -o at_analyzer at_analyzer.c -lpython3.5m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl -v`