# Cython: Compiling and Cannot Find Library Mac OSX 10.12

Tags: python, c, compilation, cython

I am just getting started with Cython and am trying to compile a "Hello World" script. I am trying to use `gcc -Os /User/Documents/Python/Test\ Python/helloCopy.c -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -l`, but I don't know what to add after the `-l`. Other forum pages say to "include -lpython2.7 (or whatever version of Python you're using) on the linker command-line" but that produces `ld: library not found for -lpython3.5
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`
Should I be directing the `-l` to a particular folder?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what resource you're using, but [this](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html) does not say anything about a `-l` flag. It suggests

> ```
> cython -a helloCopy.pyx
> ```
>
> This creates a yourmod.c file, and the -a switch produces an annotated html file of the source code. Pass the -h flag for a complete list of supported flags.
>
> ```
> gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/include/python2.7 -o helloCopy.so helloCopy.c
> ```

(Linux)

On macOS I would try to compile with

```
gcc -I/usr/bin/python -o helloCopy.so helloCopy.c
```

to use the standard version of Python.

Comment: Both of these produced an error of `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyBytes_FromStringAndSize", referenced from:
      _PyInit_helloCopy in helloCopy-d342ea.o
      ___Pyx_InitStrings in helloCopy-d342ea.o
  "_PyCode_New", referenced from:`
   ... a whole bunch more
`ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Also, how would I figure out what resource I am using?

Comment: @ConnorTingley I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105482/compile-main-python-program-using-cython) which I think you used as reference before. Do you have `python-dev` installed?

Comment: I think I do, because I am able to include the python3.5m folder successfully, but I might be totally wrong.