# gcc error - likely library

Tags: c, windows, gcc, cython

I am new to `gcc`. I am trying to compile a C file created by Cython with help from this site: [Compile main Python program using Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105482/compile-main-python-program-using-cython)

The C file was created successfully with following command:

```
cython --embed -o mycode.c mycode.py
```

I then used following gcc command:

```
gcc -Os -I E:\WinPython\python-3.6.5\include\ -o mycode mycode.c -L E:\WinPython\python-3.6.5\libs -lpython36 -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl
```

But it gives following error:

```
C:/MinGW-W64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lutil
C:/MinGW-W64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldl
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: Best solution: switch to Linux:). On a more serious note: That is seldom the case that workflows for Linux are working on Windows. You need to find tutorials for Windows.

Comment: I fully agree but for distribution, one has to build for Windows because that is what everyone has. I am sure you can find the problem here.

Comment: `lutil`, `ldl` and others are Linux libraries, not sure where or whether they are on Windows.

Comment: I think there is also another problem: When build with minwg there is no guarantee, that the extension can be used by Python build with MSVS

Comment: @ead AFAIK Python exposes a C only interface, which is well defined for windows.

Comment: @Rudi https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers states "Some alternative compilers exist like MinGW, but incompatibilities may occur with a CPython official distribution that is built with Microsoft Visual C++. " I remember some Cython-questions on SO which were resolved by switching to MSVC, but because I don't use Windows  I never have verfied them.

Comment: Sometimes you can compile under windows using mingw, or you can use visual stupidity, it has a special command line called nuget in which you can install meaningful non microsoft libraries that actually work.