# How to compile a python file with cython to an exe in windows

Tags: python, windows, exe, cython, mingw-w64

I want to compile a HelloWorld in Python with Cython using mingw-w64.
I could create the HelloWorld.c using this command:

```
cython --embed -o HelloWorld.c HelloWorld.py
```

But then I can manage to be able to generate a HelloWorld.exe

I use the following command:

```
gcc -Os -I C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include -o HelloWorld HelloWorld.c
```

And I get the following error:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x39): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I checked that there aren't any "wmain" like some threads suggest ([Compile main Python program using Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105482/compile-main-python-program-using-cython/22040484))

Python Version: 3.6
Windows 10
C Compiler: MinGW-w64

HelloWorld.py

```py
def main():
    print("Hello world!")

if __name__== "__main__":
  main()
```

Answer (score -2):

Using `pyinstaller` with `.pyd` extension is one of the easiest solution that you can get. However, I'm not sure whether you can use `--embed` or not since it may need the `.spec` or `.pyd` I guess.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried it with Pyinstaller, the problem is Pyinstaler doesn't hide the code, it only packs it in an exe, so it can be easy decompiled.

Comment: I'm having similar issue right know and trying nuitka. I will let you know if it works for hiding the code.