# Cython with Visual C++ Compiler?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, cython, python-2.6

Once I've used Cython to generate a C file, how do I use the Visual C++ 2010 compiler to make an EXE?

I've tried

```
cython.py Temp.py
cl.exe /MD /I "%ProgramFiles%\Python 2.6\include" Temp.c /link
     /LibPath:"%ProgramFiles%\Python 2.6\libs"
```

but it says

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined
```

and if I change the `/MD` option to `/MT` then I getTemp.c

```
LIBCMT.lib(crt0.obj) : error LNK2019:
  unresolved external symbol main referenced in function __tmainCRTStartup
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Cython compile to an EXE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581784/can-cython-compile-to-an-exe)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Cython does not generate the code for an executable, but for a Python module.  For example, it generates an `init<modulename>()` function, but no `main()`.  This can be changed by supplying the `--embed` option, as explained in [Embedding Cython](http://wiki.cython.org/EmbeddingCython).

See also: [Can Cython compile to an EXE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581784/can-cython-compile-to-an-exe) -- one answer even gives an example on how to do it using VC++.