# python compiler

Tags: python

I have a few queries regarding python

1. Why is there no python compiler to create native code? I have found py2exe etc but they just pack a python interpreter along with them and hence, it is again the interpreter executing the code.
2. Is it not possible to create a python compiler like a LISP compiler and hence the code will execute faster(compared to C++)?

Thanks,
Vinay

Comment: You may find this question interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138521/is-it-feasible-to-compile-python-to-machine-code

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Nuitka – Python Compiler](http://www.nuitka.net/blog/nuitka-a-python-compiler/)

> **What it is**
>
> I thought there ought to be possible to use a compiler for Python, a better compiler than what CPython already has with its bytecode. This is what Nuitka is supposed to be.
>
> It is my attempt to translate pure Python not into bytecode, but into machine code (via C++ compiler), while using libpython at run time. And then to do compile time and also run time analysis to speculatively execute things in a faster mode if certain expectations are met.

Comment: Thank you.. This is the first time i'm hearing about this after searching for quite some time, and it seems very interesting. This was something I was looking for.. :) I have not checked how it works.

Answer (score 9):

Question 1:

- [Nuitka](http://www.nuitka.net/blog/2011/12/nuitka-release-0-3-16/) (Direct Python code to C++)
- [ShedSkin](http://code.google.com/p/shedskin/) (Compiles implicitly statically typed Python to C++, stand-alone programs or
  extension modules)
- [Cython](http://cython.org/) (From a superset of Python to C
  extensions. Cython comes from [Pyrex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrex_%28programming_language%29))

Question 2:
Not sure if I get it correctly but maybe the answer is:

- [psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/) (A Just in time compiler (JIT) for Python Code, the
  predecessor of the [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) JIT )

Answer (score 2):

The nearest equivalents for Python are [cython](http://cython.org/) and [pypy](http://pypy.org/).

Answer (score 2):

There is, sort of.

1. See [Cython](http://cython.org/) -- I haven't had a chance to fully explore it yet, but as best as I can tell, it directly compiles Python code.  You can also use (optional) static typing -- it won't be vanilla Python anymore, but it can lead to a speed boost, if you do it right.  Also, see this: [Can Cython compile to an EXE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581784/can-cython-compile-to-an-exe)
2. It might be because I don't have much experience with Lisp, but I'm not entirely sure by what you mean by 'create a Python compiler like a Lisp compiler'.

Comment: I read somewhere there exists a LISP compiler and performance of LISP program is comparable to C++. Am I wrong? Can LISP  compiler create native executable?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your original question.  Yes, some Lisp compilers can create native executables.  Cython (which I linked above) does nearly the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

[Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) is a newer Python compiler based on NumPy & LLVM, which falls back to CPython.

Answer (score 1):

[LPython](https://lpython.org/): Novel, Fast, Retargetable Python Compiler.

[Taichi](https://www.taichi-lang.org/): Productive & portable high-performance programming in Python.

[Codon](https://docs.exaloop.io/codon/): A high-performance, zero-overhead, extensible Python compiler using LLVM

[Mojo](https://www.modular.com/mojo): Mojo combines the usability of Python with the performance of C, unlocking unparalleled programmability of AI hardware and extensibility of AI models.