# Create a single executable from a Python project

Tags: python, compilation, exe, packaging, software-distribution

I want to create a single executable from my Python project.  A user should be able to download and run it without needing Python installed.  If I were just distributing a package, I could use pip, wheel, and PyPI to build and distribute it, but this requires that the user has Python and knows how to install packages.  What can I use to build a self-contained executable from a Python project?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

There are several different ways of doing this.

---

The first -- and likely most common -- way is to use "freeze" style programs. These programs work by bundling together Python and your program, essentially combining them into a single executable:

- **PyInstaller:**

  [Website](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) || [Repo](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller) || [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyInstaller)

  Supports Python 3.7 - 3.10 on Windows, Mac, and Linux.
- **cx_Freeze:**

  [Website](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) || [Repo](https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze) || [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze)

  Supports Python 3.6 - 3.10 on Windows, Mac, and Linux.
- **py2exe:**

  [Website](https://www.py2exe.org/) || [Repo](https://github.com/py2exe/py2exe) || [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/)

  Supports Python 3.7 - 3.10 on Windows only.
- **py2app:**

  [Website](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) || [Repo](https://github.com/ronaldoussoren/py2app) || [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/)

  Supports Python 3.6 - 3.10 on Macs only.

The main thing to keep in mind is that these types of programs will generally only produce an exe for the operating system you run it in. So for example, running Pyinstaller in Windows will produce a Windows exe, but running Pyinstaller in Linux will produce a Linux exe. If you want to produce an exe for multiple operating systems, you will have to look into using virtual machines or something like [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/).

---

Of course, that's not the only way of doing things:

- **pynsist:**

  [Website](http://pynsist.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) || [Repo](https://github.com/takluyver/pynsist) || [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynsist)

  Pynsist will create a Windows installer for your program which will directly install Python on the user's computer instead of bundling it with your code and create shortcuts that link to your Python script.

  The pynsist tool itself requires Python 3.5+ to run, but supports bundling any version of Python with your program.

  Pynsist will create Windows installers only, but can be run from Windows, Mac, and Linux. See [their FAQ](http://pynsist.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#building-on-other-platforms) for more details.
- **Nuitka:**

  [Website](http://nuitka.net/) || [Repo (Github mirror)](https://github.com/kayhayen/Nuitka) || [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Nuitka/)

  Nuitka will literally compile your Python code and produce an exe (as opposed to the other projects, which simply include Python) to try and speed up your code. As a side effect, you'll also get a handy exe you can distribute. Note that you need to have a [C++ compiler](http://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html#requirements) available on your system.

  Supports Python 2.6 - 2.7 and Python 3.3 - 3.10 on Windows, Mac, and Linux.
- **cython:**

  [Website](http://cython.org/) || [Repo](https://github.com/cython/cython) || [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Cython/)

  Cython is similar to Nuitka in that it is a Python compiler. However, instead of directly compiling your code, it'll compile it to C. You can then take that C code and [turn your code into an exe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2581784/646543). You'll need to have a C compiler available on your system.

  Supports Python 2.7 and Python 3.3 - 3.11 on Windows, Mac, and Linux.

---

My personal preference is to use PyInstaller since it was the easiest for me to get up and running, was designed to work nicely with various popular libraries such as numpy or pygame, and has great compatibility with various OSes and Python versions.

However, I've also successfully built various exes using cx_Freeze without too much difficulty, so you should also consider trying that program out.

I haven't yet had a chance to to try pynist, Nuitka, or Cython extensively, but they seem like pretty interesting and innovative solutions. If you run into trouble using the first group of programs, it might be worthwhile to try one of these three. Since they work fundamentally differently then the Pyinstaller/cx_freeze-style programs, they might succeed in those odd edge cases where the first group fails.

In particular, I think pynist is a good way of sidestepping the entire issue of distributing your code altogether: Macs and Linux already have native support for Python, and just installing Python on Windows might genuinely be the cleanest solution. (The downside is now that you need to worry about targeting multiple versions of Python + installing libraries).

Nuitka and Cython (in my limited experience) seem to work fairly well. Again, I haven't tested them extensively myself, and so my main observation is that they seem to take much longer to produce an exe then the "freeze" style programs do.

---

All this being said, converting your Python program into an executable isn't necessarily the only way of distributing your code. To learn more about what other options are available, see the following links:

- https://packaging.python.org/overview/#packaging-python-applications
- https://docs.python-guide.org/shipping/packaging/#for-linux-distributions

Comment: Hi @Michael0x2a, I was wondering if any of these solutions can work for multiple Python scripts which has interdependencies and user input collection, at a same time and create a single .exe file? I have a Python project based which has multiple scripts for different functionalities like user inputs collection, .txt file processing, dashboard creation etc.

Comment: @DebayanPaul:  since these are packaging solutions, what you do in your code shouldn't be important, unless it has impact during package-time. I eventually used pyinstaller, which worked great

Comment: I'd discourage Cython for this. It's only really designed to compile single modules and so explicitly doesn't handle the problem of bundling dependencies (including the Python standard library)

Answer (score 20):

[pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) is under active development as of July 2022. You can see [the latest changes](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/commits/develop) on GitHub. It supports for Windows, Linux, and MacOS; 32 and 64-bit. It supports Python versions 2.6, 2.7, and 3.3+.

---

Install PyInstaller with pip:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Go to your program’s directory and run:

```
pyinstaller -F script.py
```

Find the .exe in the dist folder. Adding `-F` parameter generates a standalone .exe.

Answer (score 16):

[auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/) is a GUI for PyInstaller.

[image: Auto-py-to-exe]