# Change python output script format to exe

Tags: python

Is there any way or tool to automatically change python output script format (.py) to exe ? I want to run my app on every Windows computers including that haven't got installed python.

Comment: freeze, which comes with the standard library, and the less limited py2exe are the ones I know of.

Comment: This question has been asked many times before and is easily google-able. The first four results for "Python to Exe" are useful links.

Comment: I tried "Change Python output format to exe", but I didn't found any interesting answer.

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl Read that : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers

Comment: @Ty221 Sure, but my comment was primarily a 'duplicate' warning. I only mentioned google becuase I thought it'd be useful. Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12059509/456188 and several others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do this a while ago and I had the most success with py2exe: http://www.py2exe.org/

You create a setup.py file which gives a list of what Python code you want to include in your executable, and it packages that up along with a subset of the Python interpreter into a single exe.  Works specifically on Windows.  (Linux and Mac generally already have Python installed so it's much less of an issue there.)