# How to my "exe" from PyCharm project

Tags: python, exe, pycharm

Writing some project on Python via PyCharm.
I want to get an exe file from it.
I've tried to **"Save as->XXX.exe"** - but ,when i'm trying to execute it there is an error *"file is not supported with such kind of OS"*
p.s.
i've got win7 x64,it doesn't work on x32 too.

Comment: Use an external software package like [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: PyCharm does not have this feature yet, but have you tried this? http://www.py2exe.org/

Answer (score 42):

You cannot directly save a Python file as an exe and expect it to work -- the computer cannot automatically understand whatever code you happened to type in a text file. Instead, you need to use another program to transform your Python code into an exe.

I recommend using a program like [Pyinstaller](http://pyinstaller.org). It essentially takes the Python interpreter and bundles it with your script to turn it into a standalone exe that can be run on arbitrary computers that don't have Python installed (typically Windows computers, since Linux tends to come pre-installed with Python).

To install it, you can either download it from the linked website or use the command:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

...from the command line. Then, for the most part, you simply navigate to the folder containing your source code via the command line and run:

```
pyinstaller myscript.py
```

You can find more information about how to use Pyinstaller and customize the build process via the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/).

---

You don't necessarily have to use Pyinstaller, though. Here's a [comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12059644/646543) of different programs that can be used to turn your Python code into an executable.

Comment: So it looks like none of the python IDE's (pycharm or pydev - eclipse pluggin) have yet to incorporate the compile-to-single-executable functionality into the IDE itself. If this is not the case, please let me know. :-)

Comment: Related: [Configuring Pycharm to run Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33906539/3357935)

Comment: You can include "--onefile": pyinstaller myscript.py --onefile to have only one big .exe file

Comment: Can you convert to .EXE using PyCharm free edition, or do you need the paid version?