# Configuring Pycharm to run Pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, osx-yosemite, pyinstaller

Yes I want to create a run configuration in PyCharm to run Pyinstaller and get my executable. According to the [Pyinstaller documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#installed-commands) you should be able to locate an python script called `pyinstaller-folder/pyinstaller.py` after the installation, but it wasn't there. Then I look carefully and found this other one named `pyinstaller-folder/__main__.py` which should be the same <--(me wild guessing), so I set up my running configuration like this:

[image]

After running it, is giving me this error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/bin/python3.4 /usr/local/lib/python3.4/sit

e-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py --onefile --nowindow --osx-bundle-identifier=jg.optimizer -F --name=genoptimizer optimizer/manage.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import __version__
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It seems to require a parent module to run but, how would that look like?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The PyInstaller package is a runnable module and can be run using `python -m PyInstaller`. To configure it as a run target in PyCharm, leave the "Script" field blank, write `-m PyInstaller` in the "Interpreter Options" field, and put the PyInstaller parameters into the "Script Parameters" field.

For example:

[image: pyinstaller pycharm configuration]

PyCharm will complain that the "Script" field is empty, but it will let you run the configuration anyway.

Comment: How do you get to this window in PyCharm?

Comment: @StevenM.Vascellaro Click on the debug configurations button in the top right corner, and select "Edit Configurations..." from the menu. Then fill in the information in a new Python profile using the editor.

Answer (score 26):

After more than two years, perhaps there is a better option.

In the PyCharm menu go to *File* -> *Settings*.
In the Settings dialog find *Tools* -> *External tools* and use the green + to add a new external tool.

For example:

[image]

Then, the IDE will allow you to run it on any python script. Right click on the file and the context menu will show *External tools* -> *PyInstaller*.

Comment: Thanks so much friend!! So easy, so convenient! :) Any idea how to suppress all the warnings? They're kind of not reassuring..

Comment: Great job figuring this out!

Answer (score 7):

The run command has changed a bit since the accepted answer. You can now select a module to launch rather than editing the interpreter options.

As of writing this answer, here is how it looks like:

[image]

#### Notes:

- This solution requires to install `PyInstaller` in the virtual environment of the project.
- I am using PyCharm pro 2020.1
- Old solution should still work
- Using external tool is still a possibility. Which solution you choose is a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

Install pyinstaller in pycharm, then open the pycharm terminal and write `python -m PyInstaller`.

Answer (score 2):

So as Pycharm has newly updates, my case was a bit different as I installed `pyinstaller` from the interpreter settings as the following picture shows:

[image]

**For Linux Users**:

You could install it in both `Python 2.7` or `Python 3.7+`. Make sure to get the path of where `pyinstaller` was stored.Then in the Settings option, try to find Tools -> External tools and add a new external tool as the following picture shows:
[image]

**For Windows users**:

If you are using Pycharm or any virtual environment. Unfortunatelly Pycharm creates its local vertual environment in `venv`path once you indicate the `interpreter`. So, you should set the external tool (pyinstaller) to the real path of your python 3.7 .exe as the picture shows [image: here]

Answer (score 1):

For those of us on Windows with Anaconda trying to figure this out, I found it easiest to just set up a Bash Configuration (I believe you need the BashSupport plugin for this), and set:

- Script: `pyinstaller` (assuming pyinstaller is in your path, if not, the full path)
- Interpreter path: `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` (yes, a bash configuration can just use the standard command program)
- Interpreter options: `/C`
- Program arguments: `script_name.py` (along with any other pyinstaller arguments)
- Working Directory: `C:\Path\To\Script`

Answer (score 0):

I used it this way:

```
-y --clean --console --noupx --name="$Prompt$" "$FileName$"
```

[image: Edit Tool]

Due to `$Prompt$` macro, every time I want to build it (*right click on code -> External Tools -> PY3_PyinstallerFreeze*), it even asks the name

[image: Input]

PS - I would recommend to use global `PyInstaller` (instead of virtual environment one) like `C:\Python39\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe` above