# How do I create an executable file out of a PyCharm project using PyInstaller?

Tags: python, pycharm, pyinstaller

I have written a project in PyCharm consisting of a .py file, a .txt file, a .ico file and the regular .idea folder for PyCharm projects. All is saved in `C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myproject`.

I would like to create a single-file .exe using PyInstaller. But when I run the command `pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed myprogram.py`, I get the following error:

> 'pyinstaller.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

To my understanding, this is because "pyinstaller.exe" is not in the location in which I ran the command prompt.

However, if I run `cmd` in the pyinstaller folder (`C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts`), my project isn't there. So that doesn't work either.

What do I need to do to get my program into one .exe file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring Pycharm to run Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906539/configuring-pycharm-to-run-pyinstaller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify either file as absolute path:

`C:\Users\pemho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed myprogram.py` should work from the project folder, as well as `pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myproject\myprogram.py` from the pyinstaller folder.

Alternatively, you can add `C:\Users\pemho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts` to your system PATH (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables)).

Answer (score 1):

Run pyinstaller from your project directory, but call it as the full directory to the .exe like C:\PathTo\Pyinstaller.exe

so your cmd would look something like

C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myproject> C:\PathTo\pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed myprogram.py