# Creating an executable from a Pycharm Python Project

Tags: python, pycharm

[image]How can I take all scripts and files in my Python project directory and create a single executable. I have tried using this: [How do I create an executable file out of a PyCharm project using PyInstaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36337376/how-do-i-create-an-executable-file-out-of-a-pycharm-project-using-pyinstaller) but it does not work. I have developed the project in PyCharm and I am using Python 3.4.

[image]

Comment: Your error traceback is almost unreadable. Please edit your question and paste the error message as text.

Comment: _"C:\...\PyInstaller.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command"_ -> Have you tried entering the _correct_ path instead?

Comment: Where is PyInstaller.exe stored though as i cannot find it in the PyInstaller folder

Comment: I have found the executable

Comment: Will try this again

Comment: Try to run `pip install pyinstaller` to install pyinstaller.

Comment: Ok. The error I am getting now is "pyinstaller-script.py: error: the following arguments are required: scriptname"  But if my project folder contains 37 files, what do I do?, what script do I specify?

Comment: What i need to do is put all the listed files in the cmd snippet above into 1 executable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cx_Freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/) it's the same way that py2exe and py2app. It supports python 2.7 or highter or you can use [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)  that binds in an executable all the stuff. 
You can download it using the following command:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Or you can download it from the website