# pycharm project to exe conversion

Tags: python, pycharm, exe, cx-freeze, pycrypto

I was using Pycharm for the development of my python  project which involved libraries like win32api and Pycrypto, what is the best way to create an exe out of pycharm, using abnaconda interpreter?
please note that Cx_Freeze is not available while using the anaconda interpreter.

Comment: Sounds like compiling to a single executable [is not supported](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206588985-Create-an-executable-file-with-PyCharm) in `PyCharm`. Given that there is not a `PyCharm` specific way of solving this, the problem the looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071910/how-to-my-exe-from-pycharm-project) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059509/create-a-single-executable-from-a-python-project)

Answer (score 1):

Try [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

It worked very well if your project size is not huge. I have used many times. No problem with win32api.