# Creating an exe file for my Python project

Tags: python, exe

I have written a Python tool at work. I want to give it to a customer so they can use it as well. However I don't want to give them the source code and much rather would give them an exe file or similar or anything that doesnt plainly display the script/code I've written.

Can you recommend what I could do? Thanks.

Comment: Try to Google your title.

Comment: See duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a single executable from a Python project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059509/create-a-single-executable-from-a-python-project)

Comment: I should add that it would be good to get an executable that does not require a python installation.

Comment: You realise that most .net applications also require you to have .net installed right?.. As previously stated, you should do (and show) your own research

Comment: Duplicates of this, but you should be aware that it is easy to extract the python code from tools like py2exe, but not from Nutika.  You should also be aware that an exe file is, at best, only obfuscation, it is not a form of encryption.

Answer (score 1):

**answer1: if you need just .exe**

1) you need to get  py2exe from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/), according to your Python version.

2) Make a file called "setup.py" in the same folder as the script you want to convert, having the following code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
 import py2exe
 setup(console=['myscript.py']) #change 'myscript' to your script
```

3) Go to command prompt, navigate to that folder, and type:

```
 python setup.py py2exe
```

4) It will generate a "dist" folder in the same folder as the script. This folder contains the .exe file.

**answer2: if you need installer , uninstaller etc**

There is some list work you need to do. 
install following

1. Python
2. wxPython
3. py2exe
4. Inno

best approach is just go though existing code. 
please go through wikipad source code [here](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wikidpad/WikidPad-2.2-src.zip)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: I have now experimented with p2exe -> doesnt work with Python35 which is what I am using. Any thoughts on that? Should I try to change my code to run on python34? Or better use something like cx_Freeze?