# Python Compile File to exe with Cython

Tags: python, cython

I try to converte python program to exe file, I use Cython to convert it to .c file and now I use gcc in windows to convert the .c program to exe file but that doesn't work please how can help me and show me step by step how I do that?
Just to know I use Python 3.5 version.

Comment: You want to convert a python script to an executable or a cython script to an executable? Either way, this is a duplicate question

Comment: convert python script to executable file using cython

Comment: why would you use cython to create an executable? that's not what cython is for? you could use py2exe, cx_freeze or similar

Comment: ok,when I use py2exe or pyinstaller or cxfreeze I get exe file for my scripte but when I execute that file in other PC I have problem there is a dll file doesn't exist, But  when I see a C program compilling by code block for exemple is work...I think If I can convert py to c and than convert it to exe it will work

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059509/create-a-single-executable-from-a-python-project/12059644#12059644

Comment: However: using Cython to generate an exe will not be as useful as you think. You will _still_ require the Python dll to be present and you will most likely need large chunks of the Python standard library to be installed for any non-trivial program - it does not remove these dependencies

Comment: DavidW if is like you say Please tell me why exe file created by code block from C program work in all computers

Comment: @G.Rami I don't quite understand exactly what you're asking but: 1) the exe Cython generates links to the libpython dll file; 2) Cython does not compile any thing you import, so these files need to be in the Python path in the normal way. You cannot easily avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cx_Freeze to converte python program to exe immediately.

cx_Freeze is a set of scripts and modules for freezing Python scripts into executables.
cx_Freeze is cross platform and should work on any platform that Python itself works on. It supports Python 2.7 or higher (including Python 3).

see at: http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html

Comment: I try with that but when I run the exe file in other PC is doesn't work, dll file doesn't exist.

Comment: Which dll? copy a error message