# Can I convert my program with all my lib?

Tags: python, exe

I have actually my program who use pandas packages and glob3 and I would like to convert my program to `exe`but I don't know how to add these package when I use auto py to exe
Anyone know how can I add these package ?

Comment: you can use py2exe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a single executable from a Python project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059509/create-a-single-executable-from-a-python-project)