# How to turn python project into executable when I have multiple .py files working together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, executable

I have a python project called deduplication which works with the help of multiple scripts. As in deduplication.py makes use of readCSV.py and dbmanager.py. So how can I turn the deduplication.py into an executable if it is dependent on the other 2 .py files?

Comment: As you use pyinstaller try using auto-py-to-exe (you must install gevent as well). It gives you a GUI to work with and creates the pyinstaller code itself. This means that you can add all your .py files much easier

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059509/create-a-single-executable-from-a-python-project

Answer (score -1):

just add an .exe to your project file