# use python file as cmd command

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pip

how can i convert my python file to cmd command that can be run from anywhere on pc

for example let's call it `my_file.py`

i want the user to type the file name (without needing to specify the extension) and run the file

```
C:\Users\alsaibi\Desktop>my_file
```

and then the program execute

here it just print "Hello, World"

```
Hello, World
```

i want to upload this file to pip  so the user download it easily and it will be easy to use from cmd easily

i saw it being done in some other projects in github

you just use pip

and can use the command in cmd without cd or extension

i'm using windows 10

edit:

[project](https://github.com/vn-ki/anime-downloader) on github that use something like that

youtube-dl work just by typing youtube-dl and arguments

i want my project to work like that

another [project](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) on github

the file execute using only the file name

1 command and the file execute
and you can download it via pip

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a single executable from a Python project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059509/create-a-single-executable-from-a-python-project)

Comment: @ncopiy that doesn't answer my question

Comment: @ncopiy i want to run it from cmd as command and not turn it into exe

Comment: @ncopiy i tried turning it to exe but there are a lot of issues

Comment: Are you looking to package and distribute your program? I thought the question that @ncopiy linked would be relevant, no?

Comment: I don't have Windows handy to check, but you can use `assoc .py=python` and `ftype python=c:\path\to\python.exe` to make a .py file executable. - logout / login to make it work.

Comment: @AMC i want to distribute my program with another method

i know how to distribute the program in the method above but that's not what i'm looking for

Comment: @alsaibi _i want to distribute my program with another method_ Can you expand on that? _i know how to distribute the program in the method above but that’s not what I’m looking for_ Which method are you referring to, specifically?

Comment: @tdelaney i don't know what that command does but i tried it and logged out but it didn't work

Comment: setuptools setup.py's `entry_points["console_scripts"]` can build .exes. See https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation. Also, you can goto pypi's [search page](https://pypi.org/search/), filter for Windows and browse projects for examples.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a *setup.py* for you script and define a *console_scripts* entry point.

[Writing the Setup Script](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html)

[Packaging Command Line Scripts](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html)

After installing it with pip it should work as you described.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a file called `my_file.bat` and then in it write:

```
python3 my_file.py
```

and then just add both the `.py` and `.bat` it to the PATH. Then, you can achieve your goal: typing

```
my_file
```

and then having the output be

```
Hello, World
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/x26PBx1.png

it doesn't work

Comment: Ok, I've got a fix: Put both of those into a folder and THEN add the folder itself to the path.

Answer (score -1):

Follow and execute these commands in order

1. Rename your file

   mv my_file.py my_file
2. Add this to the beginning of your file:

   #!/usr/bin/env python
3. Make the file executable:

   chmod +x my_file
4. Now you should be able to run the file as:

   ./my_file
5. To run the file anywhere on the PC you have to move the file to  `/usr/local/bin`

   mv nameofthescript /usr/local/bin

Comment: i'm on windows 10 so that doesn't work i think


but thank you for helping

i will use it on my linux machine

Comment: There is no hard and fast rule for this, use python instead of python 3

Comment: He asked for the solution on PC. This method only works on Mac/Linux, both of which I also use.

Comment: @GOVINDDIXIT .exe can't be downloaded via pip and antivirus always delete converted python files to .exe

Comment: @GOVINDDIXIT - have you tried this? Simply renaming a file doesn't turn it into a binary executable file.

Comment: Yes, Not much idea about windows you can use pyinstaller to convert python file to .exe

Comment: This would help you https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-python-script-to-exe-file/