# How to convert py script to an exe file for other non-python users and pass a csv as an argument?

Tags: python

I have a python script that takes a csv file and a week number as arguments. How do I share my code to other non-python users through an exe file that allows them to upload the csv and input the number? The python script is very simple; it just cleans and organizes the data but I'll be sharing this to other people.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a single executable from a Python project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059509/create-a-single-executable-from-a-python-project)

Comment: take a look at this program https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/. It will convert your python script to exe files

Answer (score 0):

What pyinstaller do is to pack your python script as well as all its environment to work on (including the scripts it imports and the imported imports and the whole python executable files) to a single exe, As long as you are using '-F' option meaning a single exe file. The exe file behaves the same way the original python script does.

if you uses
`python XXX.py args`,
then now you should be using `XXX.exe args` instead.