# Ways to compile Python Code to executable File

Tags: python, exe

im wondering if there´s another way than "py2exe" or "pyinstaller" to compile a python code (3.7) into a *.exe file ?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a single executable from a Python project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059509/create-a-single-executable-from-a-python-project)

Answer (score 1):

There's a thing called py2app although I don't know if you'll have any more success with that.