# How to import external library to python automatically

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a program to python that includes a pip install of a library. How can I make it so that my friend can open the file without having to install the pip library. Is it a way to make it exe that includes the libraries?

Comment: There are several options. Just check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059509/create-a-single-executable-from-a-python-project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a single executable from a Python project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059509/create-a-single-executable-from-a-python-project)