# How to ship python projects?

Tags: python

I was curious if you made an application in python how do you ship it? If you made it in a virtual enviroment can you just give that out for download? Do you need some kind of install process?

(In my case it would be a webapp made with flask intended to run on a linux server)

Comment: What kind of application is it? Is it intended to run directly on a desktop/laptop? Or is it a web app that runs on a server? The answer to your question depends on this.

Comment: @enzo This should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Sure, will add as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to ship a python application but the most straight-forward method is to either package it (as a pip package) or `pip freeze` it's dependencies and share the code.
[Read here for more](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

> `pip freeze` will produce a similar list of the installed packages, but the output uses the format that pip install expects. A common convention is to put this list in a `requirements.txt` file:
>
> ```
> (tutorial-env) $ pip freeze > requirements.txt
> (tutorial-env) $ cat requirements.txt
> novas==3.1.1.3
> numpy==1.9.2
> requests==2.7.0
> ```
>
> The `requirements.txt` can then be committed to version control and shipped as part of an application. Users can then install all the necessary packages with `install -r`:
>
> ```
> (tutorial-env) $ python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
> Collecting novas==3.1.1.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
>  ...
> Collecting numpy==1.9.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
>  ...
> Collecting requests==2.7.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
>  ...
> Installing collected packages: novas, numpy, requests
>  Running setup.py install for novas
> Successfully installed novas-3.1.1.3 numpy-1.9.2 requests-2.7.0
> ```

---

One alternative worth mentioning is to containerize your application (using [docker](https://docker.com) or similar technology) and share it. This would help address the common "works on my machine" issue.

[Containerized Python Development](https://www.docker.com/blog/containerized-python-development-part-1/)

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would compile it as an exe or app. Some common utilities for this are [pyinstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/), [py2exe](https://pypi.org/project/py2exe/), and [py2app](https://pypi.org/project/py2app/).

Comment: wouldn't that go against python being platform agnostic?

Comment: @Tibebes.M no. Python isn't "platform-agnostic" anyways. You can't use a Python program utilizing `ctypes` and Windows DLLs on Linux, for example.

Comment: @Tibebes.M IDK... presumably the OP knows the environment into which the script would be deployed. In any case, at least one of the options I listed allows for cross-compilation. Gotta start somewhere!

Comment: @MattDMo the packages might be platform specific but the language as a whole is independent AFAIU

Comment: @Tibebes.M that is correct, but there is no requirement to make your programs as platform-agnostic as possible. Single-platform executable makers like `py2exe` and `py2app` are not looked down upon at all, as your comment would seem to suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You can dockerize it, so it can be run simply with:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

See more details in https://docs.docker.com/language/python/build-images/

Answer (score 2):

You can just upload it to a code repository like [GitHub](https://github.com/) and people can download it. Or you can just [create an executable from the project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12059509/9997212).

Answer (score 0):

In your case I'd heavily suggest you build a docker container and archive the code via git. In my experience, just doing `pip freeze > requirements.txt` does not suffice when the intended audience is not python literate. Especially issues with `venv` and `conda` setups have cost me way to many hours of my life.