# How to use virtual venv python from machine one machine to another machine?

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, python-venv, pyvenv

I am new in Python. I would like to write a python script in machine A with Ubuntu OS. After the writing script done, I want to run the script in another machine. I plan to use virtual environment.
Is it possible to copy the venv from machine A to machine B directly? My expectation I can execute the script in machine B without doing some package installation anymore. Is it possible?

Anyone can give me an advice or example please. Thank you so much.

Comment: Copying a virtual environment is not recommended. There might be library problems. It is better to create a new environment based on a `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Virtual environments are to isolate environments from each other. If you are looking for a deployment solution consider containerization solutions such as docker.

Comment: @KlausD. But if I use `requirements.txt` it means need to install some package. In the B machine there is no internet connection to download the package

Comment: @Cheries There are two approaches. 1) Create a [standalone executable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12059644/7976758); see also https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+standalone+executable ; 2) [Download all necessary wheels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758), copy them to machine B and `pip install` them there; see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline .

Comment: Since you are new in it, Is Python required? If you want to create a program without needing to download external dependencies, there are better options.