# Is there a way to embed an .mp3 file into a .py file?

Tags: python

I want to make a python application with a sound being executed when pressing a button and I also want users to download it from somewhere. But, I have to add an mp3 file to play the sound. The mp3 file must be in the same directory as the .py file. But when the user downloads it, the directory changes according to his PC. So, how will I make it so that the mp3 file is in the same directory as the .py file to recognize it and play it? Is there any way to completely add the mp3 file in the .py file without it being seperated? If yes how? Thanks!

Comment: Host the .mp3 online and play it from there...

Comment: I've never tried this myself, but I did a quick google and this looks promising: [python: can executable zip files include data files?](/q/5355694/4518341)

Comment: Seems I can convert it it to base64. Is that efficient?

Comment: Not that efficent to convert it in base64 and then decode it.

Comment: I think your question is more about how to package a python application with its dependencies, and this looks like a good answer to that question: https://medium.com/@amimahloof/how-to-package-a-python-project-with-all-of-its-dependencies-for-offline-install-7eb240b27418

Comment: There are more "efficent" types of encoding you could use, like [`base64.a85encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.a85encode). It uses a larger alphabet than standard base64 does so the result are smaller.

Comment: Here's some more information about the [Ascii85 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85) and why it's better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address this problem (including data in a Python script) I wrote [py-include](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/scripts/blob/master/py-include.py).

The core of that program is basically this:

```
with open(path, "rb") as img:
    data = img.read()
data = base64.b85encode(data).decode("ascii")
```

It encodes the binary file contents using base85 encoding and converts it to text.

An example:

```
python src/scripts/public/py-include.py /usr/local/lib/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default16.png 
# /usr/local/lib/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default16.png
data = base64.b85decode(
    'iBL{Q4GJ0x0000DNk~Le0000G0000G2nGNE03Y-JVE_OEnMp)JRCoc5j04PNM-<0@Gjs9$KCit'
    '&ZQHhO8(|qWsu|UG8`qAjU~S`j_PclH^ww_oBu9U-B_*}v9!PrmKXLkh&6|$A5hphyGE>Hndf;'
    'CJ<dw-g%3ITC^4IG0?jnl8x}@bsS$o)pf20+F+%s`UhT~7jnVaa%-GMP`>e#RDmTz`D5Z@$t3P'
    'K+MVh4l|;`z_2$?txr0Oa=R%PDkclJTkpg9Dvt>Vxk;`vjwNR-KrgvS#MMwhNfC&*xw?sHB|-z'
    'P|!xcQSJ2))xX7q6JJpMWzASXwOP%=RKQicNplbo=tVdRJ{CViX*GQ8IYtM18BQY(+W<Y9Y7wK'
    'n1X>ke!9gz=UmS&m)(k+SfOKw$WJeUZ=m6z30NTF1nsKXnMnv#LkI-Y28Ii)>L1AWt50XOoyE8'
    '<^1*#qL$?S07%B?74(WLVUOZmhG4Nwp0c;BC93(vO)Wg)gtqFrH*}#$NIcl4WP;Wyg4J89Zb*K'
    '#BY0Iayf&&r2YQ|TlSh7iAWCOm=k#j!zeoTQ)u+c)(M}jVt6*LXzMtk6a>3m~HM1#{5b)EHj!;'
    '<yGM7E1<H<5as6SjMnNve$W0@Oeosb!#<{?y#)4yu8>F!X!iG}J<NEzD=k-wdrT6Wkik9(|K-('
    '+dGmfrZEruNgtb{!I#CUGch42B)n%FwC@3eguI{ItI@rZNW&=4pIsVhHg7CtHL{}r(QhC1CYo+'
    'X?*3RPqL$>9SZ|3bQGbwzXl|&e{8{troC_obn!cHl#2iq0KnSpO#@EFZ%f!dFk5U9r22$mgwl>'
    'EQuMnay;>0+Wj^(Da?-%6$Etq{_(RZzNzetN?17>jpwQx>op~qO?@ns}u$~3T>H$)`AslTIpBD'
    'fC002ovPDHLkV1f'
)
```

Include the output from this script in your Python file, and `data` will contain the (binary) contents of the icon as `bytes`, which you can then e.g. save to a temporary file.

Note that the data will become ≈1.35 times as big because of the encoding.

`py-include` has an option to compress files before encoding, but since an MP3 file is already heavily compressed that doesn't yield a size reduction in this case.

Comment: Same with mp3 files? Basically I am trying to use bytes from the mp3 file and in the same code read the bytes and play the file

Comment: @thomastheocharis `py-include` works with any kind of file. I didn't use an MP3 as an example because they tend to be big. In my test, a 5MiB MP3 was converted into 6.8MiB python source code.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution to package your application + dependecies is to create an executable from them.

I personally use [pyInstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller) and [py2exe](https://www.py2exe.org/), but these answers cover the topic more in detail.

[How can I make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependen)

[Create a single executable from a Python project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059509/create-a-single-executable-from-a-python-project)

Comment: Didn't really work...

Comment: Did you follow the procedure thoroughly?