# How to make a program convert a .PY file to .EXE without human intervention and without GUI

Tags: python, exe

After running my python program a `myFile.py` file has been created that contains some code. I want my program to not only create `myFile.py` but also convert it to `myFile.exe`.

[auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/) or any alternative that have the same problem isn't a solution because I need to manually select the file that I want to convert in a GUI to convert it, I need **my program** to convert it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a single executable from a Python project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059509/create-a-single-executable-from-a-python-project)

Comment: call pyinstaller with the os module (`os.system(your_command_calling_pyinstaller)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be using the `cx_Freeze` library to convert .py to .exe.
To install the package enter the command `python -m pip install pypiwin32` in the terminal.

```py
import win32com.client

tempFile = open(os.path.abspath("temp\\temp.py"), 'w')
your_File = 'yourFile.py'
print("import sys\nfrom cx_Freeze import Executable, setup\n\n\nbase = None\nif sys.platform == \"win32\":\n    base = \"Win32GUI\"\nexecutables = [Executable(r\"" + yourFile + "\", base = base)]\n\nsetup(\n    name=\"exe_File\",\n    version=\"0.1\",\n    description=\"Sample cx_Freeze script\",\n    executables=executables,\n)", file = tempFile)
tempFile.close()

os.system("python \"temp\\temp.py\" build")
```