# How do you attach necessary files to GitHub repo?

Tags: github

If I have a python library I use in my GitHub project, will someone without that python package still be able to run my code after cloning my project? If not, can a python library be attached to a repo?

Also, if I have a bash file, will it still be able to run with people without bash?

Lastly, how do you attach whole languages like Python, C#, or any language inside of your repo so everyone can use your project?

Comment: Sounds like you want to deploy your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python code cannot be run without the required libraries but you can tell people to install the libraries. For example, you can run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to add all the dependencies to a file. When people wamnt to install the dependencies, they can run `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Inside a repositories `README.md`, you can tell people the required dependencies.

In addition, dependencies aren't usually bundled because of space concerns. If you have a bash file, you need bash to run it. If you want to bundle your project to include the language and all the dependencies, you can use a program such as the ones listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059509/create-a-single-executable-from-a-python-project)