# How to build a self-contained Python venv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-packaging, python-venv, python-poetry

Is that possible to build a self-contained Python virtual environment? By self-contained, I mean that all needed files to execute the program are there, **including Python.**

I'm using Poetry to manage `venv`s. Looking at `venv`s I created using `poetry install` I see that the dependencies are actually copied, but Python is simblinked.

For example:

```
>> ls -lah my-venv/bin/
python -> /Users/my-user/.pyenv/versions/3.11.2/bin/python
```

Also, I tried the `virtualenvs.options.always-copy` [Poetry config](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvsoptionsalways-copy), which translates to `--always-copy` [virtualvenv configuration](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/cli_interface.html#always-copy), but it didn't copy Python.

Since an expected answer would be "use containers", I say in advance that it's not an option for the given use case.

**This question aims to a solution that an "all-in" directory/file can be uploaded to a Linux server and just run without using depending on any system-installed software.**

Comment: The links to "external" resources are part of what makes it a *virtual* environment, rather than a "real" environment.

Comment: That's a really good comment on the semantics, actually. So may I rephrase. is there a way to package the real env all together?

Comment: Any tool to create [standalone scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12059644/7976758), https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+standalone+script

Comment: @ОлексійХолостенко Neither downvote nor upvote are mine so I cannot say.

Comment: If you want something that does not need a Python interpreter to be preinstalled then: PyInstaller as already mentioned, [*briefcase*](https://pypi.org/project/briefcase/) also, or something like [*Nuitka*](https://pypi.org/project/Nuitka/), and see also [this section of documentation "*Bringing your own Python executable*"](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/overview/#bringing-your-own-python-executable). -- Anyway, this question has been asked so many times, I am sure you can find lots of resources.

Comment: I thought of an ugly idea :)
zip micromamba and the code, and run it through a script that unpacks, create conda env, and run in it ... funny idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I found:

1. Use conda/mamba to manage the dependencies. It has the advantage of actually installing Python, which is useful for the question use case.
2. Use [conda-pack](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/) to pack in a `venv` every Python user knows how to use.

Why this approach solves the problem? Because we end up with a `venv` including actual binaries, instead of symblinks. So we can't just share it as `tar.gz` file and **no one (other than the project developers) has to learn new technologies (every average Python developer is likely to know `venv`).** It just works:

```bash
# ON THE SOURCE/CI MACHINE
$ conda pack -n my_env -o my_env.tar.gz

# ON THE USER/SERVER MACHINE
$ mkdir -p my_env
$ tar -xzf my_env.tar.gz -C my_env
$ source my_env/bin/activate
```

---

A note:
I tried using like PyInstaller and other tools people wrote in answers and comments. Honestly, they try to reinvent the wheel. For example, PyInstaller goes recursively over the imports and tries to build from the discovered imports. On my first try it didn't work for [PyArrow](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/) `*.pyx` dependencies, for example. Maybe I used it wrong. But, why invent the wheel and discover the imports if we can go explicit with major tools like standard `venv`, Poetry, and Conda/Mamba.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something that does not need a Python interpreter to be preinstalled then: [*PyInstaller*](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/) as already mentioned, [*briefcase*](https://pypi.org/project/briefcase/) also might work, [PyOxidizer](https://pypi.org/project/pyoxidizer/), or something like [*Nuitka*](https://pypi.org/project/Nuitka/). I recommend you read [this section of documentation "*Bringing your own Python executable*"](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/overview/#bringing-your-own-python-executable) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a tool like [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/). From documentation:

> PyInstaller bundles a Python application and all its dependencies into a single package. The user can run the packaged app without installing a Python interpreter or any modules.