# Create a "ready to use and share" Python app with environment

Tags: python, linux, debian, virtualenv, virtual-environment

I am developing a Python app in Debian Linux. I have my code ready and it works well on my machine with all its dependencies and modules installed.
However the purpose of this application is to be shared with different people and work for them without the need to install neither Python, nor any of its dependencies. I also have the requirement to **not** use Docker.

So with all this said, I thought I may be able to install Python in a certain directory, then create a tar file from it and somehow (magically) this would work on any other LINUX machine.
So it turned out that is not the way it works.

How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: you want the app to work on other Linux machines? Windows systems? Macs? In the question you mention "any other machine" but is not clear if your objective is that or just to run in other linux systems.

Comment: Yep, that was my mistake. I will edit my post. I need it to work on any other linux machines.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12059644/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+standalone+script

Comment: but usually Linux machines come with python preinstalled, right? Having python in this case shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Elerium115 1st, not always. 2nd, what about installing dependencies? 3rd, should a user of such a program also be a developer (virtualenv, `pip`, OS and Python dependencies)?

Comment: if python is installed, you can create a bash script that basically does `pip install -r requirements.txt`  followed by a `python myApp.py`

Comment: @Elerium115 One shouldn't run `pip install` in a global environment. 1st, it requires root rights, and 2nd it's very much not recommended to avoid breaking system packages like `apt`. `pip` in Debian/Ubuntu is patched to prevent that.

Comment: @phd I used the provided link and tried the PyInstaller approach. That did work for me! If you'd like you can post this answer, so I can mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions - use different mechanism for making container (like podman) or create virtualenv and use it to run python on different machine.

Note that virtualenvs can be little... wonky. If you copy it from Intel to ARM Mac it probably will work, but if you copy it from Windows PC to Raspberry Pi or even from Linux x86-64 machine to Raspberry Pi it won't. And probably there will be another hassle running it since python is somewhat linked to system libraries.

I don't get why you don't want to use Docker, it works just fine and is the best "friendly" scenario for your problem.

Comment: Well first of all, I am unfamiliar with Docker and also for some reason, this is also a requirement from my team.
Also if I use docker, doesn't that mean that the machines that will use the python app will need a docker installed?

Comment: Yes, that means they will need to have docker installed. Anyway there are various solutions for bundling python app depending on what it is - if it's webapp, you can bundle it via Electron or React Native + webview. Despite that, app needs to be hosted on some dedicated machine (for example that runs Apache2 + Django). If not, there are solutions based on bundling app for running it on Windows/Linux/macOS via some "portable" mechanisms (and I'm not really familiar with them).

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert it into an executable file such as ".exe" (for windows) or ".elf" (for linux). This will allow you to run the program without installing python or any other dependencies.

Comment: And... pardon... for that you need to bundle it using external solutions from github and et cetera.