Can use a virtual environment on another PC or machine on Windows
I recently shared a project of Python on Langchain and installed all the libraries in that project with my friend in which I created a virtual environment.
Can he directly use all libraries and packages from my environment without creating a new environment and installing all libraries and packages installed by me?
So is there any way by which my friend can directly run that project from a virtual environment without installing all libraries? Here, I am asking if a virtual environment capable of directly running projects on another machine/PC.
Note: I don't want to use requirement.txt, and this all process goes for Windows.

Have you considered sharing it as a docker container? You and your friend would both need to configure WSL to run the container on Windows, but it would allow you to share the complete package.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059509/create-a-single-executable-from-a-python-project , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+standalone+script

You could try configuring a remote python interpreter via ssh.
ssh <your pc host@your PC ip> -t '<path/to/your/virtual/env/bin/python> <python script on your friends pc>; bash -l'

If you are using Pycharm you can do this via GUI there and pycharm will take care of invoking something like this for you.

I think the python script your friends want to run should be in your PC
