How to have others run a python script without python
In essence, I have to run a script monthly which takes in two files and then converts them into another file (the code is very simple). I am sent the two files and then have to run it myself, but I am looking into ways that others can run the code without having python installed on their computer.
One method I've looked into is setting up a web page (e.g. using flask) where you drag and drop the files and then it spits out the output file, but this seems quite involved (I am not a developer...) or just automating the task such that it is run monthly as long as the files are named properly and put in a shared location beforehand. But I suspect there is an easier way, I just haven't come across it.
Apologies if the question seems simplistic as I am not the strongest in coding so would appreciate some guidance on this :)
I've tried setting up a basic web page - just a template, not yet functioning.

Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059509/create-a-single-executable-from-a-python-project help?

To be fair, if the script is as simple as you say, it might be simple to just re-code it in a compiled language (where you can simply distribute a binary file that can be ran)

You basically have 3 options:

Distribute your code as a web service, like you are trying to. This is pretty involved, since it requires:

setting up a server (or a cloud instance) (this has costs involved unless you already have access to one)
making a web interface for your app.


Distribute/bundle python with your app. You may want to look at pyinstaller or py2exe.
Make your script into compiled code. by either

compiling your python. this is kind of arcane, but projects like Cython (with --embed flag) or  nuitka may help
rewrite it in a compiled language. Depending on how simple your script is, this may be the simplest way



Overall, I think the easiest is either 2. (if your app is relatively big) or rewrite in a compiled language (if it is sufficiently small)

You could include an installer for python in the folder where your program is and have it execute when someone executes your main file.
If you want to run the program monthly you can just use windows time scheduler and set the file to run every 30 days.

If you are allowed to use any external library I suggest trying streamlit, as it is external you need to first install it by doing python -m pip install streamlit.
Consider following simple example, which uppercase text file, so lets' call it shouter.py
import streamlit as st

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose a file")
if uploaded_file is not None:
    bytes_data = uploaded_file.getvalue()
    text_data = bytes_data.decode("utf-8")
    bytes_upper = text_data.upper().encode("utf-8")
    st.download_button("Download file", bytes_upper)

then run it by doing
python -m streamlit run shouter.py

this will start server and now you can access page (default is http://localhost:8501) where you can provide file to conversion and after it is done you can download changed file. Above examples assumes that user will furnish text file using UTF-8 encoding.
