# Cython compile to exe, Windows

Tags: python, windows, compilation, cython, anaconda

I'm having trouble compiling Cython generated C code to an EXE on Windows.

Windows 10
Python 3.5, 32bit, Anaconda
Visual Studio 14.0

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581784/can-cython-compile-to-an-exe) stackoverflow thread, I was able to convert **test.py** to **test.c** using the command line:

```
Python C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\cython-script.py test.py --embed
```

I tried compiling **test.c** to **test.exe** again using the command line:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat x86
# (not shown) cd to test.c directory
cl.exe  /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic:\Anaconda3\include -Ic:\Anaconda3\PC /Tctest.c /link /OUT:"test.exe" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MACHINE:X86 /LIBPATH:c:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Includes\libc /LIBPATH:c:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Includes\PCbuild
```

But the result is an error message:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python35.lib'
```

I'm not sure what's causing this error, and I'm also not confident that I am pointing to the correct LIBPATH.

I haven't found a thread that solved the issue of Windows + Cython + Anaconda + Python 3.5 + C Compilation. Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

cjrh's answer below solved the initial error and the test.c successfully compiled to test.exe.

however, running test.exe produced the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding
```

The fix: create a new system variable called PYTHONPATH. In Windows, this is can be done by: 
My Computer > Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables.
Making PYTHONPATH include the below fixed the error:
 C:\Anaconda3;C:\Anaconda3\DLLs;C:Anaconda3\Lib;C:Anaconda3\Scripts

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Windows instance handy, but it looks like you may be missing the `LIBPATH` entries for linking the Python library itself, something like

```
... /LIBPATH:c:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:c:\Anaconda3\PCbuild
```