# How do I create executable for Cython project using setuptools on Windows OS?

Tags: python, cython, executable, setuptools

main.py:

```
print('test')
```

I can build using this command:

> python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=msvc

This will create *.pyd files and put them to needed folders in my package.

But my main.py is compiled as main.pyd.

```
Extension(
    'main',
    sources=['main.c','main.py'],
    include_dirs=[np.get_include()],
)
```

Tried this:

```
cl.exe  /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\P\Python27-32\include /Tcmain.c /link /OUT:"main.exe" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MACHINE:X86 /LIBPATH:C:\P\Python27-32\libs
```

But it fails:

> main.c    Creating library main.lib and object main.exp
>   MSVCRT.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Is there a way to build it as Windows executable main.exe using Cython?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making an executable in Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507592/making-an-executable-in-cython)

Comment: Or another reasonable duplicate target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581784/can-cython-compile-to-an-exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it.

setup.py has to expose entry_point:

```
entry_points={
          'console_scripts': [
            'mypackage-cli=mypackage.command_line:main',
            ],
      },
```

command_line.py:

```
from . import cli
def main():
    print cli()
```

__init__.py:

```
from markdown import markdown

def cli():
    return markdown(u'It''s a CLI!')
```

after `python setup.py develop` 
it creates executable file `mypackage-cli.exe` with 'shim' script `mypackage-cli-script.py` in %PYTHONPATH%\Scripts

```
c:\tmp\mypackage>C:\Python27-32\Scripts\mypackage-cli.exe
```

`<p>It's a CLI!</p>`

It requires Python distribution to be at `C:\Python27-32`

I posted demo here: [github:mycyexepackage](https://github.com/pydemo/mycyexepackage)

Answer (score 2):

Try use PyInstaller

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

From my experience this framework works allways

And download Cython bundling if it necessary :
https://github.com/prologic/pyinstaller-cython-bundling

Comment: I am not sure that I understand you well