# Create a python programm standalone on windows 7

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, python-standalone

I'm beginner on python, 
I'm developing a Python 3 application on my own computer (LINUX) and 
I have to give a final standalone version on Windows 64 to my teacher.

My question is how to compile a python program on Windows, what's tools are generally used to programming python on windows and how to handle dependencies module (`Sklearn`, `OpenCV`  ...etc).

Thanks in advance !

Comment: after a while i got py2exe to work

Comment: possible duplicate: [Making a python program executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286441/making-a-python-program-executable) and [py2exe generate single executable file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), or [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial), which i think is appropriate for windows.
Also [cx_freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/) if you want.

Comment: Thanks Leonardo ! py2exe seems to be fine, But if I work on windows how to test my scripts (I don't know how to install modules without PIP).