# Creating a single exe file from Python code

Tags: python, winapi, executable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [py2exe - generate single executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file)

A friend of mine managed to pack some a Ruby script he wrote in a single exe file. When I tried to do the same thing for a Python script, with py2exe, I also got several pyd files and a dll.

Is it possible to pack a Python script with all it's DLL's and pyd files into just one exe, and get rid of the other files?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [py2exe.org](http://www.py2exe.org/old/#the-bundle-option):

> The --bundle  or -b  command line switch will create less files because binary extensions, runtime dlls, and even the Python-dll itself is bundled into the executable itself, or inside the library-archive if you prefer that.
>
> ...
>
> Using a level of 1 includes the .pyd and .dll files into the zip-archive or the executable itself, and does the same for pythonXY.dll. The advantage is that you only need to distribute one file per exe, which will however be quite large.

[There's also another little tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/SingleFileExecutable) on creating a single exe which will expand DLLs into a temporary directory at runtime, then delete the tempdir when Python exits.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/SingleFileExecutable) can probably help you. More specifically, it seems that you can achieve this by setting `bundle_files` to 1 and `zipfile` to `None`. I haven't tested it, and it may not work if you have additional DLL files.

The other approach on that page seems clumsy: creating an installer that will expand the project into a temporary directory before running it, and removing the temporary directory after the application terminates.