# Using bundle_files = 1 with py2exe is not working

Tags: python, django, dll, py2exe

After some big frustration I did it! I converted my django app to an "exe" one to run as a single standalone app on windows (using cherrypy as a WSGI server)
But When I try to to set py2exe's option `"bundle_files" to "1"` (i.e. bundle the python interpreter Python25.dll inside the generated exe) the generated exe crashes with a message talking about kernel32.dll

But when I use `"bundle_file" = "2"`, the generated exe is runing like a charm, but must -of course- have Python25.dll as a separate file beside it.

Anyone experienced a similar behavior, can you please tell me what I'm missing?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Oh shoot, I know I had this problem before, but can't remember what the heck I did to fix it. :( Sorry dude. I'll return if I remember.

Comment: Dude? :) -- Thanks, Aren! Please do tell me when you remember how/why!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, but the exe crashes if I set bundle_files to 1 or 2. Only 3 works. Mine is a Tkinter GUI utility. py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.6. I've tried some googling and found reports of similar problems, but no fixes so far.

Comment: Could you provide the error message (mentioning kernel32.dll) please?

Comment: you probably mean "bundle_files": 1, not "bundle_files"= "1" nor "bundle_file" = "1". right?

Comment: Are you using windows 64bit? because "bundle_file" to "1" is not supported for 64 bits machines

Answer (score 2):

this post talks all about using py2exe to get a single exe file.

[py2exe - generate single executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file/6824876#6824876)

If you post some code i'll take a look, and your error message will help to.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) instead.

I did have this problem before and didn't find a solution ever, but pyinstaller meets my need too and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar problem. But mine is with PyGTK. Simple program has no problem with it. Although there is no straight solution, there is an explanation provided [here](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/SingleFileExecutable).

It says:

This is based on the Inno sample code in the py2exe distribution. It has worked successfully for a rather complicated PyGTK/Twisted app requiring extra data at runtime (GTK runtime data, GtkBuilder files, images, text data) that just **wouldn't work with bundle_files**.

Answer (score 0):

Here's The solution:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 3}},
    windows = [{'script': "Your_App_Name.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```