# How to freeze Python PySide file using py2exe to one exe file?

Tags: python, pyside, py2exe

I tried to freeze my `Python PySide` file to exe, it works well when I'm doing it with `'bundle_files': 3` but when i try to do it with `'bundle_files': 1` im getting this error in log:

`WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified`.

this is my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    excludes=['_ssl',  # Exclude _ssl
                                    'pyreadline', 'difflib', 'doctest', 'locale',
                                    'optparse', 'pickle', 'calendar'],  # Exclude standard library
    dll_excludes=['msvcr71.dll'],  # Exclude msvcr71
    compressed=True,  # Compress library.zip
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}},
    windows = [{'script': "myFile.py", "icon_resources": [(1, "icon.ico")]}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

This is the log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "MultiClipboard.py", line 4, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
File "PySide\__init__.pyc", line 41, in <module>
File "PySide\__init__.pyc", line 11, in _setupQtDirectories
File "PySide\_utils.pyc", line 97, in get_pyside_dir
File "PySide\_utils.pyc", line 88, in _get_win32_case_sensitive_name
File "PySide\_utils.pyc", line 63, in _get_win32_short_name
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: why this question has the tag: pyinstaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Py2exe** does not support this feature on [64-bit machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909240/using-bundle-files-1-with-py2exe-is-not-working). If you need to bundle all your project into one file, you should try to use **pyinstaller** instead